# How to (repeat) an animation for a WKInterfaceGroup not using images

Tags: swift, watchkit

I have a very simple animation so naturally I'm trying to avoid image sequences and SpriteKit.

I have simply set a WKInterfaceGroup background to green. I want it to fade in and out alpha 1.0 to 0.2 and 0.2 to 1.0 repeatedly. Call it a pulse or whatever you want.

I can fade it out using:
`self.animate(withDuration: 1.0) { row.circleBG.setAlpha(0.2) }`.

But how to I fade it back in and repeat the entire animation infinitely?

Even if I create separate fade out and fade in functions only the first call gets executed anyway so that doesn't work either. Even if it did work it won't repeat.

The only repeat method I can find requires an image sequence range like this. `row.circleBG.startAnimatingWithImages(in: (need image range), duration: 1.0, repeatCount: 100)` But I am not using images.

Of course I could use a green circle image and black circle image but that seems so unnecessary and hacky.

Attempted something like this but it actually wouldn't repeat and I need a fadein + fadeout to repeat together as one animation. The pulse fades in/fades out and repeats.

Also I can only access `row.ringStatus.` buy creating `for (index, value) in`. I would like to avoid this code repetition.

```
var pulseTimer: Timer!
pulseTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5, target: self, selector: #selector(pulse), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

  @objc func pulse() {

    for (index, value) in self.messageObject.enumerated() {
        guard let row = messagesTable.rowController(at: index) as? MessageListRowController else { continue }

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            row.ringStatus.setBackgroundColor(.green)
            row.ringStatus.setAlpha(1.0)
            row.ringStatus.setAlpha(0.2)


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can use the `Timer`? I've implemented the similar thing using the timer.

Comment: I tried it with the Timer. I saw that on another question. I could only get one fade working. Not fade out the fade in.

Comment: Can you please update your question on what you've tried? I would like to look into it, may be I can help you with that? I am specifically interested in how you're doing it with the timer?

Comment: Updated. I don't remember the exact code, but it was something like that.